# Select rows with most recent date year wise in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has multiple ID's and every row has a date.
Let's take an example of one ID

[image]

Now what I want is to create a new data frame such that for each ID, all the  rows with most recent date in each year are selected like below

[image]

I just can't seem to be able to do this. Can someone please guide me how to do this

Comment: `do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x){x$Date == max(x$Date)},
      with(df, split(within(df, {Date <- as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")}), paste0(ID, Year)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class with `mdy` from `lubridate`, grouped by 'ID', 'Year' `filter` the rows where the 'Date' is `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
     group_by(ID, Year) %>%
     filter(Date == max(Date))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work absolutely fine ! You are a life saver. I didn't even think to use filter. I was doing mutate and group_by and then didn't know what to do next. I'm new to R and still learning. Thanks a ton again !

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try the base R code below

```
subset(
  transform(df,Date = as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y")),
  as.logical(ave(Date,ID,Year,FUN = function(x) max(x)==x))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, in addition to the solution by akrun above, your solution is also running bang on! It's so good to see multiple solutions of a problem. I keep learning new things ! Cheers!

Comment: @akrun Well, I don't think it's a dupe. Quite different questions, actually.